# Requirements.txt file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to show python libraries in requirements.txt by using "pip freeze > requirements.txt" and my virtual environment is still activated.

But instead of getting my current virtual env's libraries, I am getting all the libraries in my requirements.txt file that i used in other environment earlier.

What is the issue?

Comment: If you type `env | grep VIRTUAL_ENV` do you see a path to the old virtual environment or the new one? Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualenv is certainly messed up.

To find the packages which are not required, run:

```
pip list --not-required
```

But, I think it's time to recreate your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

First you deactivate the virtual environment by,

```
source deactivate
```

Then run the `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Deactivating is done by `deactivate` by itself, no?